# not only loves but also leads her children[Connective]

Tags: grammar

She not only loves her children but also leads them.
She not only loves but also leads her children.
Which is more suitable?

Answer (score 2):

The grammar is fine in both, but that word **lead** bothers me.

Mothers **guide** their children. :)

To lead a political party; to lead a nation; to lead troops into battle. The word is pretty "loaded".

Comment: I expect learner is going for the alliteration, but I agree in this context "lead" doesn't work.  Time to break out the thesaurus!